# User data not showing unless Server starts. MERN Stack

Tags: reactjs, database, mongodb, user-interface, mern

I'm using MERN Stack for the first time to build an application. Problem is the website is live but unless I start the server from my laptop the user data on the frontend of the live website does not show up.

Now is this how it actually works?, do I need to have the server running from my laptop for user data to show on the live website?, or is there something I can do to fix this so if I don't have the server running for some reason the data on the live website can still be visible?.

Thank You.

Comment: no server - no data from server

Comment: even on the live website?.

Comment: How is your project is set up and how are you hosting? Is the client on the same server as the backend? Do they share the same domain and/or share the same process?

Comment: @MattCarlotta everything is on same server and same domain. It is a prototype. I just wanted a UI that shows the working of the application. And the tutorial/articles I followed none said anything about different servers or domain.

Comment: yes, you should better understand how databases work

Comment: @Jayzxr I'm assuming you're serving compiled client assets via express? If so, is the backend/API also using this express instance? Or is it separate?

Comment: What do you mean by *website is live*?